# Analog audio jack 3.5 mm on a raspberry pi 4

Tags: audio

I am Amaury from « Observatoire de Meudon ». I succeeded in installing Mathematica `12.2`. My application contains a command like Beep or Soundnote that produce sound!

I have problems with VLC, I have a lot of choices to select. Audio inside VLC, I do not know which case to activate, and when a correct issue is realized. I do not know how to confirm the choice!
When looking to BT that is on my toolbar, I did not so far add the two-LP speaker to be isolated in Add device!
Something is missing and that is my question!

It may be because BT is not correctly installed! hopefully the command `sudo amxplayer -local example.mp3` gives a good sound! `sudo raspi-config` is correct too!

While the command `speaker-test -c2 -l7 -twav` is correctly executed but does not produce Sound! Mom

Comment: Ah, le me see. GUI VLC interface is not perfect but already very user friendly.  (1) It is indeed very confusing which audio device to choose. My very rough guide is something like this: (1) select default if no diea, (2) if using USB sound card, then use USB. (3) Sometimes more than one option work. (4) yes, there is no confirmation yes or no, sometimes immediate effect, sometimes at the end of the main selection menu, and may vary form version to version, (5) check out the little icons at top right corner (sometime need to right click to awake them, (6) Not sure if you are suing BlueTooth.

Comment: Not sure if you are using BlueTooth. I have tested 4 BT speakers and only one works reliably, others do not have stable connection.

Comment: Hi it is Amaury, I thank tlfong01, I solved the problem, In fact a double click, at the extreme right of the tool bar : need Analog to tick,

Comment: Hi @Amaury, How nice to hear your problem solved. Cheers!